# Statistical Physics-Taylor expanding

Tags: calculus, statistics, physics, statistical-mechanics

[image]

Could please someone explain why I can make Taylor expanding around s/N.
What  about states that s is almost equal to N?

Comment: It is not guaranteed to be a good approximation there.. but it is easy to see e.g. by the central limit theorem that the distribution is quite sharply peaked near the mean if the number of steps was large, and the mean is zero by symmetry. So the probability that s is big is very small.

Answer (score 1):

So this is not really rigorous; $s$ actually ranges all the way from $-N$ to $N$ so that $s/N$ really ranges all the way from $-1$ to $1$. Near $s/N=0$, one can Taylor expand. Traditionally we expand the logarithm and then exponentiate, since the logarithm is (quantitatively) smoother. This shows that the profile looks like a Gaussian near there.

For certain purposes that's plenty. To be rigorous you would want to ask: how near is "near"? And if there are values of $s$ which are not "near", what happens there?

There are different ways to handle that. One way would be just brute force estimation (try to take more derivatives of $\ln(P(d))$ and use the Lagrange error). Another way would be a quantitative central limit theorem, such as the Berry-Esseen theorem. Indeed $d$ is a sum of $N$ independent identically distributed variables which are uniformly distributed on $\{ a,-a \}$. The mean of this is zero; the variance is $a^2$; the third absolute moment is $a^3$. So the ratio $\frac{\rho}{\sigma^3}$ (using Wikipedia's notation) in the Berry-Esseen theorem is $1$. So the uniform error in the CLT approximation is less than $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{N}}$...but probably not by a whole lot, maybe an order of magnitude or so. An interesting question for an analyst or probabilist (not so much for a physicist) is where the error is maximized.